# Create a "refund check" for a customer in quickbooks through c# code

Tags: c#, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am using Quickbooks enterprise edition 16.0

I need to create a refund check in quickbooks for a particular customer with a credit memo.

A refund check has to be created for a credit memo, for a particular customer. I have to do this programatically through c# code.

I am new to this can anyone help me with this code.

Thanks

Comment: Search for Quickbooks and .NET tutorials.This is one of the first results I found on Google, should give you an idea http://www.nullskull.com/a/1568/c-net-application-with-quickbooks-desktop-edition.aspx

Comment: Ya i checked this one, but i need info about Refund checks.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use CheckAdd to create the check. There are basic code samples included in the Onscreen Reference Guide.
http://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html
(Use scroll wheel and compatibility mode for using the OSR.)

Also, you should look at APPENDIX F OVERPAYMENTS AND REFUNDS (p569) in the Programmers Guide for the proper way to do refunds and make sure you clear the credit memo when writing the check.
https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/doc/PDF/QBSDK_ProGuide.pdf

Comment: First of all thanks for the info :) Amazing post. Basically in quickbooks i find a credit memo then create a refund for it. Here in CheckAdd() we cannot add a credit memo reference I guess. I wanted to create a "refund check" for a particular account and a particular Credit memo. I would be great if there is a example of it. I am doing it for QuickBooks enterprise edition 2016 16.0